# How to read psd Photoshop file's metadata field values into Python?

Tags: python, metadata, photoshop, keyword, field-description

How can I read a Photoshop **psd** file's metadata fields such as:
**Description**,
**Document Title** and
**Keywords**
into **Python**?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [psd-tools3 1.9.0. psd-tools3](https://pypi.org/project/psd-tools3/%20), it is a package for reading Adobe Photoshop PSD files as described in specification to Python data structures.

You can find the documentation [here](https://psd-tools2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), it's quite easy to use to be honest. You can just pip install the package with: pip install psd-tools3

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, Sean. I'll check it out in a few days and post back.